# How to read whatsapp message (phone number + body content) with nodejs and twilio?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I am able to send the whatsapp message with Twilio API, the question is how do I read the whatsapp message content (body, phone number's sender) with nodejs and twilio api? any good example?

Comment: Do you mean how do you get the contents of a whatsapp message when you receive a message to your Twilio  WhatsApp number?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you setup your WhatsApp API sandbox you are given a box to fill in with a URL for incoming messages. When a message is sent to the WhatsApp number Twilio will make a webhook, an HTTP request, to that URL with the body of the message and the sender's number.

You can see how to use this in Node in my blog post on [emoji translations of WhatsApp messages](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/08/emoji-translations-twilio-api-whatsapp-node-js.html) and it's the exact same process as [receiving an incoming SMS message with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-node-js) too.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: thanks !, is it possible without using ngrok? as ngrok is being blocked on my network.

Comment: You don't have to use ngrok, but you do need to provide a public URL somehow. You could do that with another service, like [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.github.io/www/), or by hosting on a server somewhere, or by using [Twilio Functions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/runtime/functions) like in my emoji post.